# Divide by zero on Android

Tags: infinity

Various calculators give various values when you divide by zero.Windows calculator says you that that's impossible, but Android ones give 0 or infinity.Can anyone explain why?

Comment: I guess because Windows is better than Android

Comment: zero! equals one.

Comment: Never seen a crash on Android phone @Bram28

Comment: I've got "Can't divide by $0$" on my android phone.

Comment: I have infinity

Comment: @Jetfly Maybe not a crash, but this is a bug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not answerable. The calculator was made that way. And that's all. You should ask the application's creator about this. It's possible to make a "calculator" which returns $1$ for every operation.

Comment: do you need c# example? xD

Comment: @JetFly You can make one :D

Comment: okay I will dobe it

Comment: do, sorry, that's stupid autocorrection

Comment: ready! http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=30662919476649417939

Comment: @JetFly Nice, it works "well" :D

Comment: lol, enjoy it mate